# Subscribe to multiple channels with ioredis

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ioredis

I have a broadcast server with `socket.io` and `ioredis` via node.

However, with my current form I can only subscribe to one channel a time.

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('mychannel');
```

Considering that I must have innumerable channels (one for each registered user, for instance) I cannot hard type every channel on the node server.

I've tried also `redis.subscribe('*')` but without success.

Any light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `redis.psubscribe('*')` and `redis.on('pmessage', handlerFunction)` did the trick.